# External scripts integration on Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, paypal, youtube-api, google-contacts-api

Since Chrome updated on Monday, I can't execute external scripts anymore on the Chrome extension I'm building. I was aware of those kind of modification but I just can't find an alternative to use some services that I was using since. For example:

- I wanted to use YouTube API to collect my users' video URLs of their YouTube account... It was already pretty harsh to call the API from a web browser extension... now it's not even possible anymore
- Most importantly, PayPal CheckoutV2 which is a very easy way to configure and collect money, can only be called through an external script with the client-ID (mine not that of the user) in parameter... but once again, it's stopped working on Monday. And the other way is to configure (and pay) for a server that will handle the transaction, written outside the actual application, etc.....which is not a solution I want to take.

I've checked so many times on your documentation to see an update about that kind of issues but I didn't find any.

Comment: This is a policy so you can't really circumvent it. Your only option is to try finding a way to access those API without the need for an external script. You can try asking in [extension groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions), there's always at least one official chromium developer around so let them be aware of what their policy changes are doing to extensions.

Comment: I think the root cause is the new Manifest 3.0 specs. Everything has to be done through a Service Worker now. But documentation is poor.

Comment: How about using JS interpreter? Load external script as text, then evaluate it using JS interpreter library like https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter